# Reveal div inside a TD when a tag is clicked, close others

Tags: jquery

I have TD elements with anchor tag inside them and divs which I want to be revealed when the anchor tag is clicked. Also, I want others to close when any one of them is clicked, if it;s open already.

HTML:

```
<td>
<a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a>
<div class="test"><p>test</p></div>
</td>

<td>
<a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a>
<div class="test"><p>test</p></div>
</td>
```

I tried with this JQuery but for some reason I have to click twice for it to show the div the first time, and if I then click on the second one the first one doesn't close. I don't need to add any classes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').hide();
    $('td a').on('click', function() {
        var state = $(this).next('.test').is('.open');
        if (state) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.test').removeClass('open').show();
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.test').addClass('open').hide()
                   .siblings('.test').removeClass('open').show().end()
                   .siblings('.test').not(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without saving state using [**toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle the `.active` class and [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the current test `div`.

```
$('.test').hide();

$('td a').on('click', function () {
  var $target = $(this).next('.test'); 

  $('.test').not($target).hide();
  $target.toggleClass('.active').toggle();
});
```

In addition I also use [**not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to hide all other `test divs` which are not the current one.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w99a3/) - Toggle Divs

---

I used the following HTML in the DEMO

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" /></a>

        <div class="test">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" /></a>

        <div class="test">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td div.test.open').removeClass('open');
        $(this).next('div.test').addClass('open');
    });
});
```

In your CSS, have

```
div.test { display:none; }
div.test.open { display:'block'; }
```

Comment: Not working. I don't have anything with class of 'open', maybe that's the problem.